# Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, osmand

I am trying to add file download functionality to my application using the ion library and I am getting the below mentioned exception during gradle build.

Dependency : compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'

Error Message:
Error:Execution failed for task ':OsmAnd:transformClassesWithDexForFullLegacyX86Debug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Complete Gradle Console Output:
Information:Gradle tasks [:OsmAnd:assembleFullLegacyArmv7Debug]
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
:OsmAnd:buildOsmAndCore
ANDROID_HOME is not set, trying ANDROID_SDK:
ANDROID_SDK is also not set
:OsmAnd:cleanupDuplicatesInCore
:OsmAnd:collectFonts UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectHelpContentsAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectMiscResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRegionsInfoResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRenderingStylesResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRoutingResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectVoiceAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:copyStyleIcons UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:updateNoTranslate
:OsmAnd:collectExternalResources
:OsmAnd:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:checkFullLegacyArmv7DebugManifest
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:classes UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:androidJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:cardview:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:design:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileCardviewUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileDesignUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComGithubClansFab162Library UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComKoushikduttaAsyncAndroidasync217Library UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComKoushikduttaIonIon217Library UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareFullLegacyArmv7DebugDependencies
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyArmv7DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyArmv7DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyArmv7DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:mergeFullLegacyArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyArmv7DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:mergeFullLegacyArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:processFullLegacyArmv7DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:processFullLegacyArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyArmv7DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyArmv7DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyArmv7DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:transformClassesWithDexForFullLegacyArmv7Debug
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(bsh.Interpreter$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(bsh.CollectionManager$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(bsh.SimpleNode$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':OsmAnd:transformClassesWithDexForFullLegacyArmv7Debug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1 mins 28.138 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:3 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Please help

Update:

Error Message after building bean shell from sources.

Information:Gradle tasks [:OsmAnd:assembleFullLegacyX86Debug]
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.
:OsmAnd:buildOsmAndCore
ANDROID_HOME is not set, trying ANDROID_SDK:
ANDROID_SDK is also not set
:OsmAnd:cleanupDuplicatesInCore
:OsmAnd:collectFonts UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectHelpContentsAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectMiscResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRegionsInfoResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRenderingStylesResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRoutingResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectVoiceAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:copyStyleIcons UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:updateNoTranslate
:OsmAnd:collectExternalResources
:OsmAnd:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:checkFullLegacyX86DebugManifest
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:classes UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:androidJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:cardview:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:design:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileCardviewUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareAndroidEclipseCompileDesignUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComGithubClansFab162Library UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComKoushikduttaAsyncAndroidasync217Library UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComKoushikduttaIonIon217Library UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareFullLegacyX86DebugDependencies
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyX86DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyX86DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyX86DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyX86DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:mergeFullLegacyX86DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyX86DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyX86DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:mergeFullLegacyX86DebugResources
:OsmAnd:processFullLegacyX86DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:processFullLegacyX86DebugResources
:OsmAnd:generateFullLegacyX86DebugSources
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyX86DebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyX86DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFullLegacyX86DebugSources
:OsmAnd:transformClassesWithDexForFullLegacyX86Debug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':OsmAnd:transformClassesWithDexForFullLegacyX86Debug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 2 mins 10.071 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Please provide the complete output from your Gradle console, not just those lines.

Comment: Have added the complete Gradle console output

Comment: Your problem appears to stem from your copy of BeanShell. I would recommend adding the BeanShell source as a library module in your project, if you are not doing so already. AFAIK, the last official JAR was compiled back for Java 1.4.2 and will have serious issues on Android as a result. In fact, that JAR never used to work; when I played with BeanShell, I had to compile myself a fresh JAR using Java 1.5.

Comment: @Commonsware I tried compiling bean shell from sources and after that also getting the same error.Have updated the questions with the complete error message.